# FragmentTabHost, inflation goes wrong when used in FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity using the ActionBar listnavigation where a Framelayout shows the fragments associated with the navigation item clicked. So far, so good.

One of these fragments has a layout containing a FragmentTabHost. Specifically, the layout looks like this (simplified):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="@string/user_creation_date"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_joinDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/profile_header">

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

       <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <TabWidget
               android:id="@android:id/tabs"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="0"/>

           <FrameLayout
               android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my fragment I initialize the FragmentTabHost in "onActivityCreated" as shown in the Android Documentation. Now to my problem; I receive the following error when I try to show the fragment:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(20242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(20242): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No tab known for tag null
```

I have found one thread that indicates that something fishy is going on with the FragmentTabHost, however it did not answer my question/problem: [Android FragmentTabHost - Not fully baked yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686282/android-fragmenttabhost-not-fully-baked-yet)

Does anyone have similar experiences with the FragmentTabHost?
Can someone explain this behavior?

Note: If I include the same fragment (no code changed) into the layout XML (by declaring `<fragment>`) of a FragmentActivity I encounter no issues whatsoever.

Comment: No, had to add a state to my activity and check against the state before initializing. Will test again when API 18 is released (in a week or two).